# Transposed sum of several columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have several columns of data, where I would like to display a summary table in rows, such that when more columns are added it's easy to add more summary fields by filling down.

Example data:

Data columns:

```
     K    L    M    N
1    10   20   30   40
2    5    10   15   20
etc.
```

Summary rows:

```
     A
1    15
2    30
3    45
4    60
etc.
```

So I want to be able to add columns O, P, Q, etc. in the future, and then simply fill down in column A to get more horizontal summaries from the data table.  I've found numerous ways to get a single transposed reference, but not a sum, and can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: why not just `=SUM(OFFSET($J$1:$J,0,ROW()))`?

Comment: Ah interesting, one particular variation I didn't try.  Let me give it a shot... thanks!

Comment: Well that doesn't give me anything even remotely along the lines of what I'm after, but I don't quite understand what it's doing so I'm going to dig into it and try to figure out if I can use the approach.

Comment: Aha, it does work provided I subtract 3 from ROW() due to the way my actual data is arranged.  Nice!  Let me finalize this and if it all works as I expect, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I didn't subtract the correction from the ROW() because in your sample data the first cell to be summed was labeled `A1`. And in the "real" formula, this shift is usually denoted `ROW()-ROW($ UPPER_LEFT_CELL_OF_RESULT_TABLE)-1` - this is too long for a comment

Comment: Yep no worries, I expected it would require slight tweaking for my actual dataset.  Working nicely now so thanks again and if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Strike that I see you did!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your task is formulated as follows:

*apply the function to individual columns of a specific range and place the results vertically in consecutive cells in the column*

Or the reverse problem:

*apply the function to individual rows of a specific range and place the results horizontally in consecutive cells of the row*

In both cases, the task is reduced to obtaining a certain subrange depending on the coordinates of the result cell - [**ROW()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en#null) for the first case and [**COLUMN()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en#null) for the second.

Subrange - one column or one row - can be cut from the range using [**OFFSET()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en#null). The help for this function usually does not mention that you can use not a single cell as the first parameter, but an entire range - the function will use the dimensions, height and width of this parameter to automatically fill in the optional fourth and fifth parameters `[height], [width]`

In relation to your task, you need to cut columns from the general range with an offset {0;1;2, etc.} starting from the first column of the range. In other words, the first parameter of OFFSET() is the address of the first column, the second parameter is 0 - no row shift is required, the third parameter is the row number of the cell for which the value is calculated reduced to zero. The function will get the remaining parameters from the sizes of the first parameter.

If your results table starts, for example, in cell **B5**, then the `ROW()` function will return `{5,6,7}`. It is enough to subtract `ROW($FIRST_CELL)` and you will get the desired `{0,1,2}`.

`ROW()-ROW($B$5)`

It is customary to subtract the row number of the result table header and 1 more.

`ROW()-ROW($B$4)-1`

This tradition is related to the long-fixed "circular reference" error - the formula should not refer to the cell in which the result will be placed.

So, in general terms, the problem is solved using formulas of the form

`=FUNCTION(OFFSET($FIRST_COLUMN_RANGE, 0, ROW()-ROW($HEADER_CELL)-1))`

or

`=FUNCTION(OFFSET($FIRST_ROW_RANGE, COLUMN()-COLUMN($HEADER_CELL)-1, 0))`

For the data sample you provided in your question, and for the `SUM()` function it would look like this:

`=SUM(OFFSET($J$1:$J,0,ROW()))`

Since in your sample the summation range starts from column **K**, we have the opportunity to specify the starting column to the left for the `OFFSET()` function, from column **J** - if the data range started from column **A**, we would not have such an opportunity. Due to this trick, the result of the `ROW()` function does not need to be adjusted: we took the column to the left of the data table and calculate the subranges with an offset of `{1,2,3}`. The above formula will work if you place the results starting from cell **A1**, as in your example. Otherwise, you need to correct this value.

Comment: It's going to take me some time to get my head around what you've written here, but than you for the detail!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your raw data shown is in K1:N of a sheet named `Sheet1`, and that `Sheet1` currently has a rightmost column of Col Z (i.e., you are leaving Cols O to Cols Z open for future data entry).

Suppose that the results will go into another sheet called `Sheet2`.

Place the following formula into `Sheet2` (it doesn't much matter where):

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!K:K),1,0),FILTER(Sheet1!K:Z,Sheet1!K1:Z1<>"")*1)))`

I will not be able to spend the extra time to explain fully how `MMULT` works. But `MMULT` stands for `M`atrix `MULT`iplication; and in your case, the first matrix is a sequence of the number 1 repeated as many times as you've got potential data rows, and the second matrix is your data range itself. `MMULT` multiplies what's in the Matrix1 by what's in Matrix2 and then adds those products. Since the first matrix is entirely made up of the number 1, the result is just the addition of the raw numbers by column. Those are then `TRANSPOSE`d to the orientation you wanted.

The `*1` you see is because `MMULT` requires that every element included by a number; so this simple operation will convert blanks to zeros before `MMULT` does its calculation. (This also means that you can't include text in the range which `MMULT` will act on; or, rather, if you do have text interspersed, the formula would need a modification to treat any text as a zero value. But this condition isn't shown or mentioned in your post.)

The `FILTER` limits the data set to only columns where there is data currently before `MMULT` takes over, rather than outputting zero values for as-yet-unused columns.

If you are unsure how many possible columns to the right of Col K you may wind up using, you can use this version of the formula in `Sheet2` instead:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!K1:K),1,0),FILTER(OFFSET(Sheet1!K1,0,0,ROWS(Sheet1!K1:K),COLUMNS(Sheet1!K1:1)),Sheet1!K1:1<>"")*1)))`

If your raw values don't actually start in Row 1, just change all range-reference instances of `1` to your actual starting row. (Note that you will *not* change non-range-reference instances of `1`, which have other meanings.)

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I don't want to use another sheet.  I'll experiment with this and see if there's a reason a separate sheet is required.

Comment: A separate sheet is not *required*. You just didn't mention where the output would go, so I gave you the most flexibility. If you want to use the formula(s) in the same sheet, just get rid of all instances of `Sheet1!` in the formula(s). Per your last comment to the other contributor, if your starting row isn't actually Row 1 as shown in your post, you'll have to adjust all range starts to include the actual Row of your data (e.g. change `K:K` to `K3:K`).

Comment: BTW, either of these solutions will produce results for all columns of data using just the formula given: no dragging down or change the formula as more columns of data are added to the right of the existing raw data.

Comment: Yeah part of the problem there I think is that my real sheet also has other, unrelated data below the summary table, so an ArrayFormula isn't going to work for my case.  But I have it working now and can just insert rows and fill down when I need to add more so I think I'm all set!

Comment: The array formula will work fine if you limit the ranges, e.g., `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(K3:K12),1,0),FILTER(K3:Z12,K3:Z3<>"")*1)))` ... or (second version) ... `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(K3:K12),1,0),FILTER(OFFSET(K3,0,0,ROWS(K3:K12),COLUMNS(K3:3)),K3:3<>"")*1)))`. Again, I wrote the formulas to be as flexible as possible given the absence of specifics or access to seeing your actual spreadsheet. It's always most efficient and effective to provide *realistic* data and ranges (and/or a link to a copy of the spreadsheet).

Comment: Yes but the other solution provided is far simpler/shorter, and I was able to also implement a dynamic length column that automatically grows to whatever length is required.  Needing to fill down on occasion if I add more columns, isn't a big deal and will be infrequent anyway.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please know that I am not in competition with anyone or their other answers. I provided you with no-maintenance options which, if they don't benefit you, may benefit other site visitors down the line. It's never a problem not to use a solution that doesn't meet your specific preferences. In my world, what I provided was not terribly complex; but I see how it may feel that way in your everyday life. I still maintain that providing full details and realistic data with ranges (and/or a link) in posts is the most efficient and effective route to getting the types of answers that best fit a need.

Comment: Of course, I'm simply explaining why I'm not accepting this as the answer since in my situation, it didn't accomplish what I wanted in a way I could implement.